# Appliction orientation changes to landscape if I stop a video in landscape

Tags: iphone, vimeo, movieplayer

I am working on an application in which I have embedded an iframe on a screen to show the thumbnail of a video from vimeo.com. Every thing is working perfect but when I tap to play the video it invokes iPhone's DEFAULT MOVIE PLAYER and then I rotate my iPhone to landscape and video plays in landscape mode. But if video finishes in landscape mode then the screen (on which I have added the vimeo iframe) also gets rotated in landscape mode. I need to fix it in portrait only but video should play in portrait and landscape both modes.
Thanks!

Comment: The video application allowed orientations do not depend on what's enabled in your application, do you have the landscape disabled in that particular view controller where the preview is shown ?

Comment: @A-Live Hi, I have disabled all the orientations in my application and all viewControllers only support portrait mode only using this code: 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

Comment: Do you need the app to be in the portrait mode only ? If so, please confirm `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` at info.plist is set to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` or optional `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`.

Comment: @A-Live yes, I have already done that in my application's info.plist. Note that this movie player is default player of iPhone i.e. invoked automatically when I tap on the video thumb in webView. I am not able to find any way out for this :(

Comment: That seem to be a good question for apple tech support, meanwhile you can use this "hack" to set the portrait orientation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7264053/792677

Comment: @A-Live Hi, Thanks for the link. Although this didn't help me but while reading content on this URL an idea came in my mind to solve my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we play a video in this way then iPhone's in built video player get invoked that is of class "mpinlinevideoviewcontroller". We can't control it's functionality. So I set

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

in the view controller containing the web view and now only this screen of the application supports all orientation and thus my issue got removed (but not resolved).

Answer (score 0):

Put this method in your all view controller to force them to remain always in  portrait mode

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for you response. But I am already using this fraction of code in my viewcontrollers. Note that the issue arises only after playing the video in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is : When your player stopped playing just call this function.

```
    -(void)setupOrientaion
    {

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];  
    }
```

or else post your code here. it 'll be more helpful to analyze.