# Trigger rotation in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, landscape, portrait

I'm having some lay-outing issues, when I start my app in portrait mode and then turn it to landscape mode, views opened after that are returning a wrong value for the rotation.

For instance, I open a view in landscape mode after it was rotated from portrait mode, when I log the rotation it still returns portrait mode:

```
NSLog(@"%u", [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]); // 4
NSLog(@"%f / %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); // 748.000000 / 1024.000000
```

When I rotate the iPad to portrait mode and back to landscape mode it returns the right sizes

```
NSLog(@"%u", [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]); // 1
NSLog(@"%f / %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); // 1024.000000 / 704.000000
```

Is there anything I need to do to make a newly added view adapt to the rotation?

Comment: For now I solved it with keeping track of the device width and height in my main view, probably not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Set the new frame of your views in the viewWillAppear Method. This will set all the items to the correct size, and if you are using a navigation controller this will work when pushing and popping views.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your view is loded as portrait mode for first time. So you have to check and rotate the view manually in viewDidLoad.

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) 
{

    [self.view setFrame:VIEW_LANDSCAPE_FRAME];

    //do more stuff

}
```

Comment: Where does the `orientation` come from? If I use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]]` it still returns the wrong value when added in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263985/manually-set-interface-orientation/7264053#7264053). It worked for me. It would be better to do as in the link in the `willAppear` than in the `viewDidLoad`. Also make sure that you've returned your desired orientation in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method and set the right key `UIInterfaceOrientation` in the `info.plist`.