# Set different supportedInterfaceOrientations for different UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

So, as by the question, I use the following code to set userinterfaceOrientation for the viewcontroller.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I tried setting `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` for another viewController.

Prior, I checked all the items for `Supported interface orientations` in the info-plist. Both the viewControllers returned `true`(as set in the info-plist) for all the orientations and didn't obey the above code. IT worked even in the absence of the above code. Is there anyway to restrict certain `Supported interface orientations` for particular classes? I made it working for the pre - iOS6 versions by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7264053/1424174).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by placing my supported orientation logic in a custom UINavigationController.  I then segue to the relevant view controller.

```
@implementation PortraitNavigationController

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

...

Comment: Thanks, I created a category and set different options as you did for different viewcontrollers. I referred the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/12526152/1424174

Answer (score -1):

I'd say implement your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` on every view controller to make it return only `YES` for those orientations you wish to support.

Comment: thanks for your response. But `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is depreciated in iOS6, hence its not called. Thats the problem. I was using it in pre-iOS6 versions

Comment: Sorry for my misplaced answer, I was not paying attention enough. For iOS 6, I hope someone else will chime in.